# Location Manager not obtaining GPS location properly

Tags: android

i am supposed to obtain the current location of the user , for this i have implemented the following code:

```
lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
ll = new mylocationlistener();
lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, ll);
```

Here is my LocationListener class:

```
 private class mylocationlistener implements LocationListener {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (location != null) {
            Log.d("LOCATION CHANGED", location.getLatitude() + "");
            Log.d("LOCATION CHANGED", location.getLongitude() + "");
            lat = location.getLatitude();
            lng = location.getLongitude();
            Toast.makeText(NearActivity.this, "lng=" + lng + " lat=" + lat,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            showProgress();
        }
    }
```

The above code is not setting the variables lat and lng which are global variables. Why is the GPS not able to provide the cordinates?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How long did you wait? Are you in a building?

Comment: Did your Logcat show the changed location? I believe you might just not have a GPS signal.

Comment: Are you sure onLocationChanged() was really called? It can take a while for the GPS to get a fix.

Comment: if onLocationChanged() can take a while to kick in, how to ensure that a certain task only happens once the GPS has returned cordinates...

Comment: Also onLocationChanged is not being called. i saw from the logcat, what could be the reason?

Comment: i am still without a viable solution....

Comment: why can't i use the location listener? And how does it matter if i am in a building?

Answer (score 0):

Location is a class that class that contains the properties of a location. It's not the same as the GPS provider. This is how you get your current location from the GPS provider.

```
lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Location lastKnownLoc = m.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

Comment: why can't i use LocationListener?

Comment: I must have read your code wrong or something. You should use it if you want constant updates of the user's location.

Comment: @Janne Oksanen I am using that and I get `lastKnownLoc` as `null`

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the permissions?

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`